# How do I migrate my KDE settings?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, kde

I like distro-hopping a lot, and currently, I'm on Arch with KDE Plasma.

I want to replicate the look and feel of my current setup on Debian.

By "the entire theme," I mean including sidebars, widgets, colors, window transparencies, login theme, SDDM theme, splash screen, wallpapers, window wobbling jelly thing, fonts, font sizes, etc.

How can I do that? Is there an "Export" button I can click?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 folders in Debian for your current KDE user configuration:

`~/.config`

`~/.local`

`~/.kde`

You have to take a look what you need, you don't need all the folders, because there are also the folders of your installed programs/apps.

> **I'm not sure if you can export it one-to-one like that and import it from Arch to Debian easily, or if it's unfortunately better to set it
> up completely from scratch again on your new Debian.**

**Take also a look at [Plasma Customization Saver](https://store.kde.org/p/1298955/).**

These are the files for my KDE with Dolphin backup and export, to a second desktop:

**KDE-Dolphin main configuration:**

`~/.config/dolphinrc`

`~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin`

`~/.local/share/dolphin/view_properties`

`~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin/dolphinui.rc.`

**KDE-Dolphin sidebar and bookmark configuration:**

`~/.local/share/user-places.xbel`

**KDE-Dolphin keyboard shortcuts configuration:**

`~/.config/kdeglobals`

`~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`

`~/.config/khotkeysrc`

**This is an old description and differently depending on the system and no longer up-to-date:**

> The majority of KDE settings are stored in hidden directories under
> your home folder. You can copy these directories to your new Debian
> installation. The main directories you want to copy are this:

`~/.config`

- Contains various configuration files for KDE applications and the Plasma desktop

`~/.local/share/plasma`

- Contains the desktop and panel settings

`~/.local/share/kwin`

- Contains window manager settings, including window decorations and effects

`~/.local/share/color-schemes`

- Contains your custom color schemes

`~/.local/share/aurorae`

- Contains window decoration themes

`~/.local/share/fonts`

- Contains any custom fonts you might have installed

`~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme`

- Contains your custom desktop themes

`~/.local/share/sddm`

- Contains the SDDM (login manager) theme settings

`~/.local/share/ksplash`

- Contains the splash screen settings